# My kotlin code gives the wrong answer for the largest and smallest values in a list and I don't know why

Tags: kotlin

This was a simple code wars question but my code gives the wrong answer for the largest value and smallest value. I have checked every section but I can't seem to make it work. I have looked at the solutions for this problem but I wanted to find out what I was doing wrong in the first place.

```kotlin
fun highAndLow(numbers: String): String {

    val splitNum = numbers.split(" ")

    var largestNum = splitNum[0]
    var smallestNum = splitNum[0]

    for (num in splitNum) {

        if (largestNum < num) {
            largestNum = num
        }
        
        if (num < smallestNum) {
            smallestNum = num
        }
    }

    return "$largestNum $smallestNum"

}

fun main() {
    print(highAndLow("8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4 9"))

}
```

Expected output: 42 -9

Current output: 9 -1

Comment: You're treating the individual values purely as string, so I guess comparing with `<` in Kotlin is equivalent to using `compareTo` which applies a lexicographical order. You'll want to convert the strings to number before comparing them. Also, in the future it would be nice to include the expected and actual output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings, not integers. Use toInt() to convert a string into an integer.

```
    val splitNum = numbers.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
```

A little tip by the way: perhaps the code could be optimised even further. Have a look here:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by-or-null.html

and

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by-or-null.html